# What exactly is the readAheadLimit of BufferReader.Mark()

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am confused about what exactly is the int ReadAhead Limit in mark(int readAheadLimit).

In a huge file if the buffer is marked what should be its value ?

Thanks

Comment: It should be how far you might want to wind back. It is how much it will buffer so you can wind back that much.

Comment: Possibly related: [What is mark and reset in BufferedReader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240071/what-is-mark-and-reset-in-bufferedreader)

Comment: is it in bytes ? For Huge files, if I mark back 1000 records, then how will I know the exact value ? Does it has any system performance issues ?