# What are some real uses cases for the methods skip and reset in BufferedReader?

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader, java-io

I'm trying to find out, what are the methods `mark()` and `reset()` of [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) really useful for?

I understand what they are doing, but for going back and forth in some text I never used them - usually I solve this problem by reading either a sequence of chars or the whole line in an array or *StringBuilder* and go back and forth through it.

I believe there must be some reason why these methods are present in the *BufferedReader* and other *Reader* implementations supporting it but I'm unable to make an assumption why.

Does the usage of `mark()` & `reset` provide some benefit compared to reading the data in our own array and navigating through it?

I've searched through the codebase of one of my large projects I'm working on (mainly *Java* backend using *Spring Boot*), with lots of dependencies on the classpath and the only thing for which the mark & reset methods were used (in only very few libraries) was skipping an optional BOM character at the beginning of a text file. And even for this simple use case, I find it a bit contrived to do it that way.

Also, I was searching for other tutorials and on Stackoverflow (e.g. [What are mark and reset in BufferedReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240071/what-are-mark-and-reset-in-bufferedreader)) and couldn't find any explanation why to actually solve these kinds of problems using *mark & reset*. All code examples only explain what the methods are doing on "hello world" examples (jumping from one position in the stream back to a previous position for no particular reason). Nowhere I could find any explanation why someone should actually use it among other ways which sound more elegant and aren't really of worse performance.

Comment: There are few if any 'common use cases'. I've never used them seriously (production code) in 22 years.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used them myself, but a case that springs to mind is where you want to copy the data into a structure that needs to be sized correctly.

When reading streams and copying data into a target data structure (perhaps after parsing it), you always have the problem that you don't know how big to make your target in advance. The mark/rewind feature lets you mark, read the stream, parse it quickly to calculate the size, reset, allocate the memory, and then re-parse copying the data this time. There are of course other ways of doing it (e.g., using your own dynamic buffer), but if your code is already centered around the Reader concept then mark/reset lets you stay with that.

That said, even BufferedReader's own `readLine` method doesn't use this technique (it creates a StringBuffer internally).