# How to do that in.readLine() starts always with first line

Tags: java

I am trying to learn a little bit Java and wanted to create a number with queue machine, but I want to `file.readLine()` starts always with first line when I use this command in `while`.

```
while (true) {
    int line = 0;
    if (in.readLine() != null) {
        line++;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `in`? What do you mean with "always with first line"? You're counting lines in a file so if you managed to make it always return the first line, you would have an infinite loop and `count` will quickly go over the maximum number that can be held in an `int`.

Comment: Perhaps you want `int line = 0;` to go _before_ the`while`, rather than _inside_ of the loop?

Comment: I wanted to use 'line' later on to describe how many lines are used in text file.

Comment: BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
                (new FileReader("en_fil.txt"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your `in` in `in.readLine()` refer to?

First  you should create a `BufferedReader` after you import `java.io.*`

```
import java.io.*;   
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int line = 0;

while (true) {
        if (br.readLine() != null){
            line++;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
```

This will start by reading the first line if that's what you mean by "starts always with first line when i use this command in 'while'" but if you mean you always want to start by the first line when the `while` is `true` then that means it will create an infinite loop.

Also note that you should put the `int line=0` outside the `while loop` or else every time your code enters that loop it will reset the `int line` to 0.

Comment: yes thats what i want it to do but i want count how much lines are "used", so thats why i put it inside while loop.
I did like You did but instead of br i have in

Comment: @CDDJoey no that logic is wrong, you should put them outside the ```loop```, because everytime you enter the loop everything inside it will be executed unless there's an error or a ```break``` inside the ```loop``` so if you put ```int line=0;``` inside your loop, that means everytime your code enters it it will set your ```int line``` to 0, this is why you put it outside the loop, if my answer is the correct one kindly accept it.

Comment: @CDDJoey what does your ```in``` refer to? does it refer to a file or to an input by the user??

Comment: I understand what You mean but i want the loop to reset it every signle time, 'in' refers to a text file

Comment: I want to know if is it possible to move later on 'br.readLKine()' back to the first line and read it again? Thats why i want it to be in the loop, for reading and reading changes

Comment: @CDDJoey oh okay, the only way i could think of accomplishing that task it to use the method ```mark()``` to mark the beginning of the file and then do a ```reset()``` which will take back the pointer to the mark(in your case the beginning of the file) but if you do that inside a ```while(true)``` loop then it will make an infinite loop

Comment: @CDDJoey here a link to answer which explains about the mark and reset methods of the buffered reader: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8240545/11367165